# Conditional count with group by in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a simple messaging system - keeping all the messages in a single table. Each message can(and should) be associated with one of the 3 other tables, that represent some sections of the website. Here is the create table statement

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `table1_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `table2_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `table3_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_unread` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

For each message, from `table1_id, table2_id and table3_id` if some column has value, it means the rest 2 are null. Here is the sqlfiddle structure and example data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b98a2/1/0.

So, `table1_id, table2_id and table3_id` are sort of threads, that I am using when grouping - to show the list of messages. Here is my query

```
SELECT 
  id,
  table1_id,
  table2_id,
  table3_id,
  message,
  from_user_id,
  to_user_id,
  COUNT(table1_id) AS t1_count,
  COUNT(table2_id) AS t2_count,
  COUNT(table3_id) AS t3_count,
  MAX(CASE WHEN to_user_id = 10 AND is_unread = 1 THEN 1 END) AS is_unread,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN to_user_id = 10 THEN 1 END) AS inbox_count
FROM
  messages
WHERE to_user_id = 10 OR from_user_id = 10
GROUP BY table1_id,
  table2_id,
  table3_id
ORDER BY id DESC
```

and this is in sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b98a2/2/0

This query works fine when I have to show all the messages, but if e.g. I want to show only inbox of the user with `id = 10` I have to check the condition that for each thread there is at least one received message, so for that I tried to apply the condition `AND inbox_count > 0`, which resulted an error `Unknown column 'inbox_count' in 'where clause'`.

I am trying to list messages similar to gmail - showing the number of total messages(`t1_count, t2_count or t3_count`) per thread, that is why I can not remove the `OR from_user_id = 10` part.

Why it can not find that column and how I can apply that condition to show the list of received(outgoing) only messages.

Comment: `inbox_count` is a computed column and not available in `where` clauses

Comment: We have differing definitions of 'simple'. This is poor design.

Comment: @Strawberry ))) just wanted to say that I do not have any nested threads/messages or messages that are connected to others are replies.

Comment: @Strawberry, could u pls give me a hint which way it would not be poor.

Comment: Any time you have enumerated columns (n1,n2,n3... etc - above n2 anyway), alarm bells should start ringing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I completely misunderstand your intent... If you want to filter with `inbox_count > 0` to then I think you want to add a

```
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN to_user_id = 10 THEN 1 END) > 0
```

after the `group by` clause. This would remove the "threads" that don't have any message with `to_user = 10`.

[See this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63e57/6) for and example.

Comment: @dav Actually you can use `HAVING inbox_count > 0` instead of the case expression as inbox_count is defined when the having clause is parsed.